# Integrating Custom Data Store (Rest API) with an ETL tool - what spec to follow?

Tags: java, database, apache, rest, etl

I have a rest api responsible for data-ingest and persisting into system for reporting purposes. The schema of such data is flat and can come from any data source like CSV, SQL table, Zendesk, Salesforce, etc. My understanding is, any ETL tools should be able to list collections, query schema and let user map fields accordingly before loading data into.

Are there any standard protocols (like ) that I should implement to enable quick integration with popular ETL tools?

I could find following ones, but not sure which ETL tool supports what?

1. [OAI-PMH](http://www.openarchives.org/pmh/)
2. [Apache MetaModel](http://metamodel.apache.org/)

Comment: Such an interesting question and only 14 views :( Need community views on how to build such API to integration with ETL.

Comment: I don't understand this question. The whole point of an ETL is that `it` will support plenty of interfaces. So if you choose to use Apache MetaModel, then that's your interface and behind it, you can have CSV, SQL, Salesforce etc.

Comment: If the question is whether or not there are standard protocols to integrate into multiple ETL tools, then I guess no, the ETL tool should already provide that standard protocol, it's the purpose of an ETL tool, imo.

Comment: @MattKo I am looking for any standard/spec that most of ETL tools follows. E.g. if I expose my data-store as SQL endpoint, then possibilities are vast.

Comment: So why don't you expose it as SQL ? That's probably supported by almost all ETL tools.

Comment: @MattKo did not think of that yet. We wanted to make it towards REST API.  Agreed, SQL supports open unlimited opportunities.